# Find variance and autocorrelations for AR(3) model

Tags: probability, statistics, time-series

$r_t -.01 = .4(r_{t-1} - .01) + .3(r_{t-2}-.01) + .23(r_{t-3} - .01) + a_t$

I found $E[r_t] = .01$ and that $r_t$ is weakly stationary.

Now, $Var(r_t) = E[r_t^2] - E[r_t]^2$ so I just need to find $E[r_t^2]$.

$E[r_t^2] = E[r_t(.01 +.4(r_{t-1} - .01) + .3(r_{t-2}-.01) + .23(r_{t-3} - .01)]$

$= .01^2 + .4\gamma_1 + .3\gamma_2 + .23\gamma_3 + \sigma_a^2$

where do I go from here?  I am having the same problem in solving for the covariances ($\gamma_l = Cov(r_t, r_{t-l}$) where I don't know what to do for $E[r_tr_{t-k}]$

Comment: You take the variance on both sides, by the stationary assumptions, the variance of $r_t$ is independent of $t$. Then you can solve the variance. Next you apply the covariance on both sides several times, you should obtain a system of equations in solving the auto-covaraince function.

Comment: @BGM Wait so $Var(r_t) = (.4^2 + .3^2 + .23^2)Var(r_t) + \sigma_a^2 + \sum Cov( )$?  What are those covariances?

Comment: I have the wrong comment at the first part -  you are not solving the variance immediately yet. You next consider the covariance of different time lag and then have the systems.

Comment: @BGM so I have four equations for the four gamma values?

Comment: Yes, for time lag $0, 1, 2, 3$.

Comment: @BGM Should the answer be that the covariances are 0?  That doesnt make sense to me at all, but someone else told me that its $\sigma_a^2*(.4^2+.3^2+.23^2)^{-1}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90533/discussion-between-john-smith-and-bgm).